# parallelization of bnlearn (with parallel package)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using the `R` package `bnlearn` to estimate Bayesian network structures. It has a built-in parallelization using the `parallel` package. However, that doesn't work.

Using the example from the manpage [`bnlearn::parallel integration`](http://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/parallel.html):

```
library(parallel)
library(bnlearn)

cl = makeCluster(2)

# check it works.
clusterEvalQ(cl, runif(10))    # -> this works

data(learning.test)
res = gs(learning.test, cluster = cl)
```

Here i get the error `"Error in check.cluster(cluster) : cluster is not a valid cluster object."`

Does anybody know how to get this working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug. Please report it to the package maintainer.

Here is the code of `check.cluster`:

```
function (cluster) 
{
    if (is.null(cluster)) 
        return(TRUE)
    if (any(class(cluster) %!in% supported.clusters)) 
        stop("cluster is not a valid cluster object.")
    if (!requireNamespace("parallel")) 
        stop("this function requires the parallel package.")
    if (!isClusterRunning(cluster)) 
        stop("the cluster is stopped.")
}
```

Now, if you look at the class of `cl`:

```
class(cl)
#[1] "SOCKcluster" "cluster"
```

Let's reproduce the check:

```
bnlearn:::supported.clusters
#[1] "MPIcluster"  "PVMcluster"  "SOCKcluster"

`%!in%` <- function (x, table) {
  match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) == 0L
}
any(class(cl) %!in% bnlearn:::supported.clusters)
#[1] TRUE
```

`cluster` is not in `supported.clusters`. I believe, the function should only check if the cluster has a supported class and not if it has an unsupported class.

As a work-around you could change `supported.clusters`:

```
assignInNamespace("supported.clusters", 
                  c("cluster", "MPIcluster",  
                    "PVMcluster", "SOCKcluster"), 
                  "bnlearn")
```